# how to get continuation of square matrices with periodic diagonal band automatically?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to write a function that can automatically analyze any square matrices with periodic band diagonals and give continuations of them. But I can't figure out an elegant way to do this.

Suppose we have written such a function called `continuation`, and suppose we have an example square matrix `mat` of order 8 as

$\small \mathtt{mat}=\begin{pmatrix}
 y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} \\
 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y \\
\end{pmatrix}$

then `continuation[mat][n]` can give a square matrix that is a continuation of original `mat` with order n. For example:

```
continuation[mat][9]
```

should give a continuation of mat of order 9 as following

$\small \begin{pmatrix}
 y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

**How to write such a `continuation` function which can automatically analyze square matrices with periodic diagonal band and give general continuation version?**

The list representation of `mat` is here:

```
mat = {{0.2 + y, 2 t1, 0.2, t1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {2 t1, 0.2 - y, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0.2, 0, 0.2 + y, 2 t1, 0.2, t1, 0, 0},
       {t1, 0.2, 2 t1, 0.2 - y, 0, 0.2, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2 + y, 2 t1, 0.2, t1},
       {0, 0, t1, 0.2, 2 t1, 0.2 - y, 0, 0.2},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2 + y, 2 t1},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, t1, 0.2, 2 t1, 0.2 - y}}
```

Comment: This is quite a complex task, unless you specify what exact type of continuations you mean...
You say periodic, so I would guess start by writing a peroid-finding function for lists...

Answer (score 3):

Using the function `FindTransientRepeat[]`, we can do the following:

```
mat = SparseArray[mat];
m = 10; {lo, up} = MinMax[mat["NonzeroPositions"].{-1, 1}];
sp = SparseArray[Table[With[{d = Diagonal[mat, k], p = Abs[k]}, 
                            Band[If[k >= 0, Identity, Reverse][{1, p + 1}]] ->
                            (PadRight[#1, m - p, #2] & @@ FindTransientRepeat[d, 2])],
                       {k, lo, up}]];

MatrixForm[sp]
```

$$\tiny\begin{pmatrix}
 y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this new `FindTransientRepeat[]` function +1

Answer (score 2):

Since no one gave a satisfactory answer, I figured out a way myself which combines `Band`, `Diagonal` and `SparseArray`.

1. The `Diagonal[m,k]`gives the elements on the $k^{th}$ diagonal of m,
   illustrated as below:

   [image]
2. `Band` in `SparseArray` can repeat the values cyclically, for
   example:

   ```
   SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {5, 5}] -> {x, y, z}, {5, 5}] // MatrixForm
   ```

   gives

   $\begin{pmatrix}  x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & y & 0 & 0 &
   0 \\  0 & 0 & z & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & x & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y
   \\ \end{pmatrix}$
3. `Tally` can find the cyclic sequence, since `Tally` tallies the
   elements in list, listing all distinct elements together with their
   multiplicities. for example:

   ```
   Tally[Diagonal[mat]]
   ```

   gives

   ```
   {{0.2 + y, 4}, {0.2 - y, 4}}
   ```

   so

   ```
   Tally[Diagonal[mat]][[;;,1]]
   ```

   give the cyclic sequence {0.2 + y, 0.2 - y}

**So combine these 3 features we got a version of the code of `continuation` as below:**

```
Clear[continuation];
continuation[mat_, order_] := 
 Module[{DiagtoBand, orderofmat = Length@mat},

  (*DiagtoBand is used for changing diagonal index to Band parameter*)  

  DiagtoBand[i_] := 
   If[Positive[
     i], {{1, i + 1}, {order - i, order}}, {{1 - i, 1}, {order, 
      order + i}}];

  (*if the order required is less then the order of mat, 
  then we just simply ArrayPad it. On the other hand, we continue it. *)

  If[order <= orderofmat,
   ArrayPad[mat, {0, order - orderofmat}], 
   MatrixForm@
    Normal@SparseArray[
      Table[(Band @@ DiagtoBand[i]) -> 
        Tally[Diagonal[mat, i]][[;; , 1]], {i, -orderofmat + 1, 
        orderofmat - 1}], {order, order}]]]
```

The `continuation` function is now universal.

```
continuation[mat,9]
```

gives

$\small \begin{pmatrix}
 y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 & \text{t1} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 & 0.2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{t1} & 0.2 & 2 \text{t1} & 0.2\, -y & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & y+0.2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You might be able to do better with `FindLinearRecurrence` than with the Tally approach. In any case, glad to see you've come up with something you can use.

Comment: @bills Thank you for suggesting `FindLinearRecurrence`. But I found that `FindLinearRecurrence` needs at least 5 elements in a list. So I think I just stick with `Tally` approach which is easy and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `Band` and `SparseArray` may be what you are looking for:

```
n = {9, 9}; 
Normal[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> y + 0.2, Band[{1, 3}] -> 0.2, 
    Band[{1, 2}, n] -> {2 t1, 0}, Band[{3, 1}, n] -> {t1, 0}},  n]] // MatrixForm
```

Just increase the dimensions in the variable `n` and the specified pattern(s) continue.

Comment: Thank you! I know `band` function. But you misunderstood me. I want a function `continuation` which can automatically analyze any square matrix `mat` we feed to it, and give general version `continuation[mat]`?

Comment: What you gave is a manual version.

Comment: So -- you want a function that's like `FindSequenceFunction` but works on matrices as well?