# How to find period of a discrete sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, periodic-function

For example,

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

has period 1, the base is {1}

```
{1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}
```

has period 3, the base is {1,2}

I notice there is a built-in function `FunctionPeriod`, but it doesn't work. eg

```
l[n_]:={1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}[[n]]
FunctionPeriod[l[n],n,Integers]
```

So how to write a function `period` to find the period of discrete sequence.

ps: The sequence could be non-integers, for example sqrt, reals,

Comment: The sequences you show are not periodic at all. But if you apply `Differences` to them, you do get a periodic sequence.

Comment: I think you are using "period" in a different sense from what I'm accustomed to. To use some examples, $1,2,1,2,\dots$ is a $2$-periodic sequence, and $3,3,\dots$ is $1$-periodic.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, the "period" is in the sense of crystallography. The crystal structure is periodic. We talk about base and primitive translation vector in condensed matter physics. `{1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}` could be viewed as the coordinates of atoms in 1d crystal

Comment: @Szabolcs I drop a comment to J.M.

Comment: In that case: `FunctionPeriod[FindSequenceFunction[Differences[{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11}], k], k]`.

Comment: @J.M. The result should be 3.  Because translate {1,2} by 3 we got {4,5}

Comment: @J.M. Enlightened by you and Szabolcs. I figure out this works `period[list_] := (list[[# + 1]] - list[[1]]) &@
  Length[Tally[Differences[list]]]`. `period[{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11}]` gives 3

Comment: Might I suggest answering your own question, if you think you've figured it out? :)

Comment: @J.M. The sequence 1,2,1,2,... has three periods.

Comment: Modulo the already noted issue of taking successive differences, there is this [prior related post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80163/finding-the-period-of-an-array-of-integers).

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for giving me the opportunity. I answered my own question. I won't forget this was enlightened by you and Szabolcs :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Oh, thank you for reminding this. I should add that I want the minimal period.

Comment: @J.M. I found a bug in my code. `Tally` will not work for `{1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3}`. In my previous post quite related to this one http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69128/4742 , bill suggest me to use "FindLinearRecurrence`. It works, but I don't understand this function, does it always give the right period?

Comment: @J.M. I understand `FindLinearRecurrence`. I should use this. I have modified my answer.

Comment: closely related: [80163](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80163/5478)

Comment: @Kuba the search function of stack exchange should be blamed :) I didn't find this post before. Thank you for providing the link

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
list={1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11}
```

then `Differences[list]` transform is `list` to periodic form

```
{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
```

`Length@FindLinearRecurrence@Rationalize@Differences[list]` gives the periodicity is `2`

`Rationalize` is necessary for real number list

But we want the translation period, so we can make the following

```
list[[2+1]]-list[[1]]
```

this gives the result `3`

So the function that serves this purpose can be defined as

```
Clear[discreteperiod];
discreteperiod[list_] := Module[
  {recurrence = FindLinearRecurrence@Rationalize@Differences@list},
  If[Head[recurrence] === FindLinearRecurrence, 
   Print["The period contained in the list is not enough"]; 
   Abort[], (list[[# + 1]] - list[[1]]) &@Length[recurrence]]]
```